# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Managed Identity App Service Error On Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

I am just new to Azure Cloud and Devops, so forgive me if I may forget some critical info here.

So during creation of tasks for the release and selecting subscriptions, I get an error when trying to authorize the subscription (which I suspect is because of insufficient permissions associated to my account), so I go to advanced options to select the managed identity authentication.

After which no error shows now. So I set all remaining items and assign Deploy Azure App Service task. However during the running of the agent I get an error during Deploy Azure App Service step.

`Error: Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name 'sample-vue'. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request`

I have already set my azure app service to have a system assigned managed identity, but still this error occurs. I can't find any answer, online, with regards to the error above so hoping that someone could help explain to me the problem and how to possibly fix it. My hunch now is that I may have some insufficient permissions, but I don't know what it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following items:

1. Remove and re-add the service connection in DevOps.
2. Check the rights of the account on Azure subscription. Please verify if the account has at least contributor access on Azure subscriptions. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator